# How to filter list elements from enum in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, filtering

I am working on Angular 2 with Typescript, and I have a scenario where I have to filter elements from a list after comparing with enum. Like -

```
let products: Array<IProduct> = [A, B, C, D, E, F];
```

below is my enum-

```
    export const enum ProductType {
        A= 0,
        B= 1,
        C= 2       
   }
```

Now I want to return a list with below elements after checking into enum-

```
let filteredProductList: Array<IProduct> = [A, B, C];
```

Currently I am doing it via switch case but I want some proper solution. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `const` from **Enum** and access to the enum like this `ProductType['C']`

**Enum**

```
export enum ProductType {
        A= 0,
        B= 1,
        C= 2       
}
```

**Example**

```
products.forEach(element => {
   let valueInEnum = ProductType[element]; 
   console.log("valueInEnum = "+ valueInEnum);
});
```

Comment: its giving me an error that "element" can't use an index in below line 

let valueInEnum = ProductType[element];

Comment: **note** remove the **const** from the enum. The idea is to get the value from the array products and and this value use it as index in the enum like this ProductType[“C”]

Comment: did you get it?